# This file does not exist and there was no index.html found in the current directory or 404.html in the root directory

Tags: reactjs, firebase, deployment, firebase-hosting

I am building a personal website with React and Firebase hosting. Everything is great except when someone clicks one of the routes (eg. `personal-website/resume`) and refreshes, this error page shows up:

> *Page Not Found
>
> This file does not exist and there was no index.html found in the
> current directory or 404.html in the root directory.
>
> Why am I seeing this?
>
> You may have deployed the wrong directory for your application. Check
> your firebase.json and make sure the public directory is pointing to a
> directory that contains an index.html file. You can also add a
> 404.html in the root of your site to replace this page with a custom error page.*

To reproduce this error you can head to my repo: https://github.com/harperzhu/Personal-Portfolio

I tried to incorporate some of the solution that has already been offered:

[SOLUTION 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247450/firebase-deploy-404-cant-find-index-html):
I checked my `firebase.json` and ensured that it was pointing to my build folder and added the rewrite snippet. This is what my `firebase.json` looks like now

```
"{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "hosting": {
      "port": 3000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  },
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

SOLUTION 2: I tried adding a `404.html` at the root directory (also where `firebase.json` is at) to point to the `errorPage.js` I have written to handle the error. Now when I input `firebase emulators: start` and refresh`/resume`, instead of showing me the error message I saw previously, now I see an empty page. Same when I deployed the website using `firebase deploy`

My 404.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Page Not Found</title>
    <script src="/static/js/main.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script
      src="/frontend/personal-website/src/components/ErrorPage.js"
      defer
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

SOLUTION 3: I tried to run `npm run build` every time before I started using the Firebase emulator. I notice that it is deleting and giving me a new `/build` folder every time with a newly generated index.html but without `404.html` (I am a little confused by that - isn't it supposed to generate a `404.html` as well?

I also made sure that I did deploy at the level of  `personal website` and the build folder does have an index HTML: ```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons.js"></script>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-v" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>Harper Zhu | Personal Portfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
Here is my folder structure: 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVKqG.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IRJQ.png
```

Comment: Check the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#firebase) to check that you've followed all suggested/recommended steps.